# Setting binding redirects for owstimer on multiple WFE

Tags: assembly-references, timer-service, owstimer

We have code similar to what is described [in this blog post](http://kwizcom.blogspot.ca/2011/02/assembly-redirection-in-owstimer.html) to set binding redirects in owstimer.exe.config using the FeatureInstalled event; the post specifically states that this event should run on each WFE, but testing shows that it is running on one, arbitrary WFE (when the feature is deployed using stsadm or Central Admin).

I am wondering if there is perhaps some setting that can be changed to cause the event to run on every WFE, or if that blog post is just plain wrong (and if the latter, if anyone has a suggestion on a better way than manually editing the config on each WFE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't my forte but I ran across the note below on this [MSDN posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464297%28v=office.14%29.aspx); perhaps that will help.

> If you wanted a job to run on all servers, including application
>   servers, your class should derive from SPServiceJobDefinition. Pass
>   the timer service (SPFarm.Local.TimerService) as the SPService
>   parameter of the SPServiceJobDefinition(String, SPService)
>   constructor.

Comment: I found this other source who also found that FeatureInstalled doesn't run on all servers, and that a timer job is the way to go, and the author of the original blog post responded to my comment saying he's found it unreliable on a retract/deploy. http://geekswithblogs.net/cicorias/archive/2010/01/31/deployment-of-theme-and-resource-files-via-feature--timer.aspx